# Convert a dates from Tweet hydrator to standard date format in Google Sheets mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: date, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a large dataset (close to 80,000) of tweets dated like this:

Wed Oct 05 01:20:53 +0000 2016

What script can I run to convert the dates in Google Sheets to the simple mm/dd/yyyy form?
In this case, it should be: 10/05/2016
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format of the date is you mentioned is consistent, you can use the below formula (assuming the date is in cell A1)

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,4) & MID(A1,5,3) & MID(A1,9,2))
```

This will extract the Datevalue from the string and then you can format it to look in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=arrayformula(if(A1:A="",,1*(regexextract(A1,"\d{2}")&"/"&regexextract(A1,"\D+ (\D+) ")&"/"&regexextract(A1,".* (\d+)"))))
```

or (with hours/minutes/seconds)

```
=arrayformula(if(A1:A="",,1*(regexextract(A1,"\d{2}")&"/"&regexextract(A1,"\D+ (\D+) ")&"/"&regexextract(A1,".* (\d+)"))+regexextract(A1,"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}")))
```

and define the appropriate format

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

`=index(ifna(Text(1&RegexExtract(A:A,".*?\s(.*?)\s"),"MM")&"/"&RegexExtract(A:A,"\d{2}")&"/"&RegexExtract(A:A,".*\s(.*)")))`

Or

`=index(text(regexreplace(regexreplace(A:A,"\+0000\s",),"(.*)(\d+:\d+:\d+)\s(.*)","$1$3 $2"),"mm/dd/yyyy"))`

Or

`=index(text(regexreplace(A:A,"(.*\s)(\d+:.*)\+.*\s(.*)","$1$3 $2"),"mm/dd/yyyy"))` 
[image]